# $T: \mathcal H \to \operatorname{ran}(T) \subset \mathcal H$ that is injective?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T \in L(\mathcal H)$ and $w(T) := \{ \langle Tx,x \rangle : \|x\| = 1\}$ be the numerical range of $T$. My question concerns a part of the proof of $\sigma(T) \subseteq \overline{w(T)}$:

First, let $\lambda \notin \overline{w(T)}$ and $c:= d(\lambda,w(T)) > 0$.
Then it's easy to show that: $ c \le \|(\lambda I - T)x\|$ 
for $x \in \mathcal H, \|x\| = 1 $.

By that, in the proof, it is followed that $(\lambda I - T)$ is invertible and $(\lambda I - T)^{-1}: \operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - T) \to \mathcal H$ (which is continuous by the Open Mapping Theorem).

The thing is that the proof doesn't stop here because next you show that $\operatorname{ran}(\lambda I - T) = \mathcal H$.

Here is my question: Is there a (linear) operator $T: \mathcal H \to \operatorname{ran}(T) \subset \mathcal H$ that is injective? What about, when $T$ is closed in $\mathcal H$?

Comment: By the way, I am used to seeing the capital letter $W(T)$ rather than $w(T)$ to denote numerical range, but perhaps notation here differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such an operator.  For instance, consider the "right-shift operator" on $\ell^2$ given by
$$
T(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots) = (0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots)
$$
Verify that $T$ is injective, but $\operatorname{ran}(T)$ is a (closed) subspace of $\mathcal H$ with codimension $1$. Since $T$ is a bounded operator, it is also closed.

Comment: In general, non-surjective isometries all act like this operator.  Another notable class of examples here is that of the injective compact operators.

Comment: Do I see this correctly that for "right-shift operator" $T$ on $\ell^2$, $0 \notin \rho(T)$ because $T^{-1}$ is not defined on $\mathcal H \setminus\operatorname{ran}(T)$?

Comment: Under the usual terminology, we should say that $0$ **is** an element of $\rho(T)$ since, as you said, $T^{-1}$ is not defined on all of $\mathcal H$.  Notably, we can call $0$ an element of the [residual spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Residual_spectrum) of $T$.

Comment: According to wikipedia, $0 \in \sigma(T)$ equivalently, $0 \notin \rho(T)$.

Comment: @Pazu whoops! I was reading $\rho(T)$ as $\sigma(T)$ in my head.  Looks like you're all set then.